# MySQL Specific "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1."

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-insert

without trigger my code works fine and i can update table using CSV file. But when create this trigger it says "Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1." . I want to know where is the problem. Thanks in advance!

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER show_last_update
AFTER UPDATE 
ON LIST
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (OLD.COMPANY_ID != NEW.COMPANY_ID,
    OLD.COMPANY_NAME != NEW.COMPANY_NAME,
    OLD.COMPANY_DATE_REG != NEW.COMPANY_DATE_REG,
    OLD.COMPANY_ID_NO != NEW.COMPANY_ID_NO,
    OLD.COMPANY_ADDRESS != NEW.COMPANY_ADDRESS,
    OLD.COMPANY_AREA != NEW.COMPANY_AREA,
    OLD.COMPANY_MUNICIPALITY != NEW.COMPANY_MUNICIPALITY,
    OLD.COMPANY_LOCATION != NEW.COMPANY_LOCATION,
    OLD.COMPANY_END_DATE != NEW.COMPANY_END_DATE,
    OLD.COMPANY_DATE_REG_SPEC_MODE != NEW.COMPANY_DATE_REG_SPEC_MODE,
    OLD.COMPANY_DATE_START_SPEC_MODE != NEW.COMPANY_DATE_START_SPEC_MODE,
    OLD.COMPANY_DATE_END_SPEC_MODE != NEW.COMPANY_DATE_END_SPEC_MODE)
THEN
INSERT INTO SHOW_CHANGES(
    COMPANY_ID, 
    COMPANY_NAME,
    COMPANY_DATE_REG,
    COMPANY_ID_NO,
    COMPANY_ADDRESS,
    COMPANY_AREA,
    COMPANY_MUNICIPALITY,
    COMPANY_LOCATION,
    COMPANY_END_DATE,
    COMPANY_DATE_REG_SPEC_MODE,
    COMPANY_DATE_START_SPEC_MODE,
    COMPANY_DATE_END_SPEC_MODE,
    CHANGED_ON) 
     VALUES(
    OLD.COMPANY_ID, 
    OLD.COMPANY_NAME,
    OLD.COMPANY_DATE_REG,
    OLD.COMPANY_ID_NO,
    OLD.COMPANY_ADDRESS,
    OLD.COMPANY_AREA,
    OLD.COMPANY_MUNICIPALITY,
    OLD.COMPANY_LOCATION,
    OLD.COMPANY_END_DATE,
    OLD.COMPANY_DATE_REG_SPEC_MODE,
    OLD.COMPANY_DATE_START_SPEC_MODE,
    OLD.COMPANY_DATE_END_SPEC_MODE,
    NOW());
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I removed PHP tag because this question involves no PHP and I removed error-handling tag because the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/error-handling/info) says "Error Handling comprises design of the code that handles errors". Your question is about an error - not about code that handles errors

Comment: Use the operator (OR, AND) you need. `OLD.COMPANY_ID != NEW.COMPANY_ID OR OLD.COMPANY_NAME != NEW.COMPANY_NAME ...`.

Comment: ok no problem....i just need answer

Comment: when i do that i can update but then the trigger doesnt work

Comment: See my test [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e3c3/1).